# Authentication failed on admin database with just-created credentials

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm trying to set up authorization on MongoDB server, but following different guides brings me to the same error :

> "Authentication failed"

[The account has been added successfully to Users table on Admin database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kZjs.png), but once I set "authorization: enabled" I cannot connect to neither `127.0.0.1` nor `localhost` with the credentials I've specified above.  [Admin database connection return "Authentication failed" error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN6ST.png) with password specified and ["Failed to load list of databases"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT3Rd.png) without authentication settings specified.

What may be the reason for this? Google results mostly suggest updating MongoDB shell, but mine is the latest (3.4.10).

Comment: The password you see in the first screen cap is not the _actual_ password, but a hash. Are you typing your real password? Or the hash literal? The hash will not work. Which guide are you following, and how did you create this user?

Comment: 1) I know what a hash is. I'm trying to enter the original password, which is as simple as "admin".
2) The user was created by adding a user to the "Users" table in Admin database. I was following a few guides that involved creating the user via console, but that resulted in exactly the same thing - me being unable to login as such user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem magically fixed itself by creating the user for around 5th time via console. I see no changes to the methods I used, meaning it's most likely mongodb's fault or even my installation's. The question will be closed, but the answer as to why this happened still remains open for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows: Please set mongodb **path** in **environment variable** because sometimes **powershell** or **Command Prompt** have issue connecting to direct server or running mongo commands